# How to get all the list names in a site from the client side?

Tags: javascript, content-query-web-part

I try to dynamically get the names of all the lists in my site using a content query web part, but apparently a CQWB can only retrieve the items in the list, but not the list name? I'm wondering how can i go this, maybe using jquery? Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 4):

+1 @james

Here's the documentation to the SPServices library. 
http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices

There isn't an example on there, but I'll post one here:

```
    $().SPServices({ 
        operation: "GetListCollection", 
        completefunc: function( xData, Status ) {
            console.log( Status );
            console.log( xData.responseText );

            $( xData.responseXML ).find("Lists > List").each(function() {
                var $node = $(this);

                console.log( $node.attr("Title") );
            });
        } 
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was wondering if it can list out all the items inside the List and their types. (refer to qns - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44282/retrieve-sharepoint-list-and-library-their-items-name

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the JavaScript Client Object Model:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var lists = web.get_lists();
    clientContext.load(lists);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListsQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListsQueryFailed));

    function onListsQuerySucceeded() {
        var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
            //Do something with oList.
        }
    }  

    function onListsQueryFailed(sender,args) {
        alert("Failed: "+ args.get_message());      }
},"sp.js");
```

Answer (score 2):

GetListCollection in Lists.asmx will get this for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.getlistcollection.aspx

Not yet sure if [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) has implemented this, if not - give @[sympmarc](http://twitter.com/sympmarc) a shout on Twitter and suggest it to him :)

Comment: SPServices currently does not have a wrapper for GetListCollection according to the documentation.

Comment: Just checked - http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices - apparently it does? I'll let Marc add more info.

Comment: herpaderp, there just aren't any example pages of it being used.

Comment: GetListCollection has been there since way back in v0.2.3. Forever!