# Retrieve SharePoint list (and library) & their items name

Tags: list, library

I have the following code that will help me to retrieve all the List in my SharePoint list. However, I have a few questions as follows:

[1] How do I set it such that it will only display those SharePoint list that is customized and created by me?

[2] How do I retrieve all the items name and their types of each SharePoint list that is return to me? (Currently, I can only return the total number of items for each list)

[3] How do I retrieve all the library in my SharePoint list?

```
    $().SPServices({ 
            operation: "GetListCollection", 
            completefunc: function( xData, Status ) {
                console.log( Status );
                console.log( xData.responseText );


                $( xData.responseXML ).find("Lists > List").each(function() {
                    var $node = $(this);

                    console.log( $node.attr("Title") );
                    console.log( $node.attr("ImageUrl") );
                    console.log( $node.attr("DefaultViewUrl") );
                    console.log( $node.attr("Description") );
                    console.log( $node.attr("Created") );
                    console.log( $node.attr("Modified") );
                    console.log( $node.attr("ItemCount") );

                    console.log("===");


                });
            } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an XML dump from the web service call. I've not done this before, but to answer your first question, you may be able to hone in on the Author attribute of each list. It appears to have the user id, so a simple check for that should be all you'll need.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <GetListCollectionResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
        <GetListCollectionResult>
            <Lists>
                <List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{8423DC5D-C083-41C2-A28D-DAF3AF74B369}" Title="fpdatasources" Description="" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itdl.png" Name="{8423DC5D-C083-41C2-A28D-DAF3AF74B369}" BaseType="1" FeatureId="00bfea71-f381-423d-b9d1-da7a54c50110" ServerTemplate="110" Created="20120711 03:13:24" Modified="20120711 03:13:24" LastDeleted="20120711 03:13:24" Version="0" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="" WebImageWidth="" WebImageHeight="" Flags="135432" ItemCount="0" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="1" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/SPDev" WebId="a01bc02b-34f9-4391-bbdb-d2a82b9c7768" SendToLocation="" ScopeId="fa7b0ddb-e1c4-4999-bf54-b1912a2e9466" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" WorkFlowId="" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="" AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="False" EnableModeration="False" EnableVersioning="False" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="True" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="False" RequireCheckout="False" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="True" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="False" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="5000" />
                <List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="/SPDev/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{E337C86E-8373-4A4F-A3FD-1EB58FBED882}" Title="Master Page Gallery" Description="Use the master page gallery to store master pages. The master pages in this gallery are available to this site and any sites underneath it." ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itdl.png" Name="{E337C86E-8373-4A4F-A3FD-1EB58FBED882}" BaseType="1" FeatureId="" ServerTemplate="116" Created="20120506 07:12:54" Modified="20120621 02:13:50" LastDeleted="20120506 07:12:54" Version="5" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="" WebImageWidth="" WebImageHeight="" Flags="41947548" ItemCount="3" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="1" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/SPDev" WebId="a01bc02b-34f9-4391-bbdb-d2a82b9c7768" SendToLocation="" ScopeId="fa7b0ddb-e1c4-4999-bf54-b1912a2e9466" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" WorkFlowId="" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="" AllowDeletion="False" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="False" EnableModeration="False" EnableVersioning="True" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="True" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="False" RequireCheckout="False" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="True" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="True" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="5000" />
                <List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="/SPDev/Lists/ProjectAdmin/AllItems.aspx" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{E57BC9B7-1675-4B58-B794-136A5606BC18}" Title=" Project Administration" Description="" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itgen.png" Name="{E57BC9B7-1675-4B58-B794-136A5606BC18}" BaseType="0" FeatureId="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100" ServerTemplate="100" Created="20120711 03:04:30" Modified="20120718 12:36:57" LastDeleted="20120718 12:16:50" Version="39" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="" WebImageWidth="" WebImageHeight="" Flags="549457928" ItemCount="7" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="1" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/SPDev" WebId="a01bc02b-34f9-4391-bbdb-d2a82b9c7768" SendToLocation="" ScopeId="b8927c31-76c5-4063-891d-dbc9293f9cbf" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" WorkFlowId="" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="" AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="False" EnableModeration="False" EnableVersioning="False" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="False" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="False" RequireCheckout="False" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="False" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="False" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="5000" />
                <List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="/SPDev/Lists/ProjectInfo/AllItems.aspx" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{83509614-ECBD-4DEB-A1C6-718578A82569}" Title=" Project Info" Description="" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itcontct.png" Name="{83509614-ECBD-4DEB-A1C6-718578A82569}" BaseType="0" FeatureId="00bfea71-7e6d-4186-9ba8-c047ac750105" ServerTemplate="105" Created="20120710 08:12:13" Modified="20120719 01:03:01" LastDeleted="20120718 12:16:42" Version="102" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="" WebImageWidth="" WebImageHeight="" Flags="616566784" ItemCount="7" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="1" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/SPDev" WebId="a01bc02b-34f9-4391-bbdb-d2a82b9c7768" SendToLocation="" ScopeId="fa7b0ddb-e1c4-4999-bf54-b1912a2e9466" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" WorkFlowId="" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="" AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="True" EnableModeration="False" EnableVersioning="False" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="False" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="False" RequireCheckout="False" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="False" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="False" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="5000" />
                <List DocTemplateUrl="/SPDev/pages/Forms/_webpartpage.htm" DefaultViewUrl="/SPDev/pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{6EA1D15C-EC6B-4D5D-A072-1C549E073A46}" Title="pages" Description="" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itdl.png" Name="{6EA1D15C-EC6B-4D5D-A072-1C549E073A46}" BaseType="1" FeatureId="00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101" ServerTemplate="101" Created="20120506 07:16:30" Modified="20120829 06:57:42" LastDeleted="20120714 06:24:04" Version="17" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="" WebImageWidth="" WebImageHeight="" Flags="12587144" ItemCount="8" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="1" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/SPDev" WebId="a01bc02b-34f9-4391-bbdb-d2a82b9c7768" SendToLocation="|" ScopeId="fa7b0ddb-e1c4-4999-bf54-b1912a2e9466" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" WorkFlowId="" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="" AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="False" EnableModeration="False" EnableVersioning="True" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="False" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="False" RequireCheckout="False" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="True" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="False" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="5000" />
                <List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="/SPDev/Lists/ProjectTasks/AllItems.aspx" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{37747111-B544-4752-8AEF-FD2B2FF10ACC}" Title="Project Tasks" Description="" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itissue.png" Name="{37747111-B544-4752-8AEF-FD2B2FF10ACC}" BaseType="5" FeatureId="00bfea71-5932-4f9c-ad71-1557e5751100" ServerTemplate="1100" Created="20120808 12:56:57" Modified="20120824 08:23:33" LastDeleted="20120824 08:23:33" Version="83" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="" WebImageWidth="" WebImageHeight="" Flags="616566912" ItemCount="42" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="1" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/SPDev" WebId="a01bc02b-34f9-4391-bbdb-d2a82b9c7768" SendToLocation="" ScopeId="fa7b0ddb-e1c4-4999-bf54-b1912a2e9466" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" WorkFlowId="" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="" AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="True" EnableModeration="False" EnableVersioning="True" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="False" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="False" RequireCheckout="False" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="False" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="False" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="5000" EnableAssignedToEmail="False" />
                <List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="/SPDev/Lists/Projects/gantt.aspx" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{49AFC299-FC30-4EE9-9571-50B3B366969E}" Title="Projects" Description="" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itgantt.png" Name="{49AFC299-FC30-4EE9-9571-50B3B366969E}" BaseType="0" FeatureId="00bfea71-513d-4ca0-96c2-6a47775c0119" ServerTemplate="150" Created="20120808 12:54:59" Modified="20120828 12:11:52" LastDeleted="20120808 12:54:59" Version="4" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="" WebImageWidth="" WebImageHeight="" Flags="549457920" ItemCount="23" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="1" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/SPDev" WebId="a01bc02b-34f9-4391-bbdb-d2a82b9c7768" SendToLocation="" ScopeId="fa7b0ddb-e1c4-4999-bf54-b1912a2e9466" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" WorkFlowId="" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="" AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="True" EnableModeration="False" EnableVersioning="False" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="False" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="False" RequireCheckout="False" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="False" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="False" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="5000" />
                <List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="/SPDev/scripts/Forms/AllItems.aspx" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{65B97AAC-AF58-4A11-8ED5-791B5E4D3633}" Title="scripts" Description="" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itdl.png" Name="{65B97AAC-AF58-4A11-8ED5-791B5E4D3633}" BaseType="1" FeatureId="00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101" ServerTemplate="101" Created="20120506 07:19:03" Modified="20120829 04:33:37" LastDeleted="20120630 01:54:59" Version="4" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="" WebImageWidth="" WebImageHeight="" Flags="8392840" ItemCount="78" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="1" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/SPDev" WebId="a01bc02b-34f9-4391-bbdb-d2a82b9c7768" SendToLocation="" ScopeId="fa7b0ddb-e1c4-4999-bf54-b1912a2e9466" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" WorkFlowId="" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="" AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="False" EnableModeration="False" EnableVersioning="True" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="False" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="False" RequireCheckout="False" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="True" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="False" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="5000" />
                <List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="/SPDev/SitePages/Forms/AllPages.aspx" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{81AE07D3-AA27-4FE1-8B24-F2B31CD1C0B2}" Title="Site Pages" Description="Use this library to create and store pages on this site." ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itwp.png" Name="{81AE07D3-AA27-4FE1-8B24-F2B31CD1C0B2}" BaseType="1" FeatureId="00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18" ServerTemplate="119" Created="20120615 06:28:12" Modified="20120801 04:33:55" LastDeleted="20120801 04:33:55" Version="4" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="" WebImageWidth="" WebImageHeight="" Flags="545263752" ItemCount="2" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="1" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/SPDev" WebId="a01bc02b-34f9-4391-bbdb-d2a82b9c7768" SendToLocation="" ScopeId="fa7b0ddb-e1c4-4999-bf54-b1912a2e9466" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" WorkFlowId="" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="" AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="False" EnableModeration="False" EnableVersioning="True" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="False" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="False" RequireCheckout="False" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="False" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="True" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="5000" />
                <List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="/SPDev/SiteImages/Forms/AllItems.aspx" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{8D08C7F3-BE02-4B27-9D92-6496439F0230}" Title="SiteImages" Description="" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itil.png" Name="{8D08C7F3-BE02-4B27-9D92-6496439F0230}" BaseType="1" FeatureId="00bfea71-52d4-45b3-b544-b1c71b620109" ServerTemplate="109" Created="20120626 07:30:52" Modified="20120821 02:42:51" LastDeleted="20120626 07:30:52" Version="4" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="160" WebImageWidth="640" WebImageHeight="480" Flags="8392712" ItemCount="8" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="1" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/SPDev" WebId="a01bc02b-34f9-4391-bbdb-d2a82b9c7768" SendToLocation="" ScopeId="fa7b0ddb-e1c4-4999-bf54-b1912a2e9466" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" WorkFlowId="" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="" AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="False" EnableModeration="False" EnableVersioning="False" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="False" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="False" RequireCheckout="False" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="True" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="False" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="5000" />
                <List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="/SPDev/Lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{FA2AB648-85DE-4068-83E5-F7EEA1BB4DD2}" Title="Tasks" Description="" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/ittask.png" Name="{FA2AB648-85DE-4068-83E5-F7EEA1BB4DD2}" BaseType="0" FeatureId="00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107" ServerTemplate="107" Created="20120711 03:20:07" Modified="20120711 03:33:14" LastDeleted="20120711 03:20:07" Version="23" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="" WebImageWidth="" WebImageHeight="" Flags="549458112" ItemCount="0" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="1" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/SPDev" WebId="a01bc02b-34f9-4391-bbdb-d2a82b9c7768" SendToLocation="" ScopeId="fa7b0ddb-e1c4-4999-bf54-b1912a2e9466" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" WorkFlowId="" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="" AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="True" EnableModeration="False" EnableVersioning="True" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="False" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="False" RequireCheckout="False" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="False" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="False" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="5000" />
                <List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="/SPDev/Lists/Workflow History/AllItems.aspx" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{23D8F766-E056-40F0-89FB-5D242CA9E056}" Title="Workflow History" Description="" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itwfh.png" Name="{23D8F766-E056-40F0-89FB-5D242CA9E056}" BaseType="0" FeatureId="00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-305cf7030140" ServerTemplate="140" Created="20120711 03:20:09" Modified="20120718 12:35:04" LastDeleted="20120711 03:20:09" Version="1" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="" WebImageWidth="" WebImageHeight="" Flags="536875272" ItemCount="59" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="1" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/SPDev" WebId="a01bc02b-34f9-4391-bbdb-d2a82b9c7768" SendToLocation="" ScopeId="fa7b0ddb-e1c4-4999-bf54-b1912a2e9466" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" WorkFlowId="" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="" AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="False" EnableModeration="False" EnableVersioning="False" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="True" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="False" RequireCheckout="False" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="False" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="False" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="5000" />
                <List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{857C769E-64A8-4E55-9BB2-76D688A474B2}" Title="Workflows" Description="" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itdl.png" Name="{857C769E-64A8-4E55-9BB2-76D688A474B2}" BaseType="1" FeatureId="00bfea71-f600-43f6-a895-40c0de7b0117" ServerTemplate="117" Created="20120711 03:29:45" Modified="20120828 09:43:43" LastDeleted="20120828 09:43:43" Version="5" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="" WebImageWidth="" WebImageHeight="" Flags="8524168" ItemCount="5" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="1" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/SPDev" WebId="a01bc02b-34f9-4391-bbdb-d2a82b9c7768" SendToLocation="" ScopeId="fa7b0ddb-e1c4-4999-bf54-b1912a2e9466" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" WorkFlowId="" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="" AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="False" EnableModeration="False" EnableVersioning="True" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="True" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="False" RequireCheckout="False" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="True" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="False" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="5000" />
            </Lists>
        </GetListCollectionResult>
    </GetListCollectionResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

So if I'm right, your code should be:

```
      $().SPServices({ 
            operation: "GetListCollection", 
            completefunc: function( xData, Status ) {
                console.log( Status );
                console.log( xData.responseText );
                var userId = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
                     fieldName: "ID"
                });

                $( xData.responseXML ).find("Lists > List").each(function() {
                    var $node = $(this);

                    if( userId == $node.attr("Author") ) {
                           //do something clever
                    }

                });
            } 
    });
```

As for #2 and #3, there are many examples on how to use [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) riddled throughout the codeplex site.  Read over the docs on how to use the library and post back specific questions about your code.

Comment: I have edited your solution cause there is another error. Also, I notice that some of the List that return to me is also not created by me such as the `Workflow History` and `Workflow`.

Comment: Awesome... It wasn't tested, just a starting point. Hope it helped.