# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined at Array.<anonymous>

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, error, jsom

I want to retrieve all the lists title of my SharePoint site and add in them into a list.

But the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined  at Array." appeared in the console.

Here is my script :

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(checkPermissions, "sp.js");

function checkPermissions(){

var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var listObject = context.get_web().get_lists();
context.load(listObject);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListsQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListsQueryFailed));

function onListsQuerySucceeded() {
    var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        var oListTitle = oList.get_title();
        //Ajout du titre de la liste dans la liste "Permissions Rights"
        var lstObject = lists.getByTitle("Droits d'accès");
        var listItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        var newItem = lstObject.addItem(listItemCreationInfo);
        newItem.set_item('Titre', oListTitle);
        newItem.update();
    }
}  

function onListsQueryFailed(sender,args) {
    alert("Failed: "+ args.get_message());      
}
}
```

I don't know why and where?

Could someone help me please?

**UPDATE :**

This code works thanks to the answers :

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var lists = web.get_lists();
clientContext.load(lists);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onListsQuerySucceeded, onListsQueryFailed);
var lstObject = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Droits d'accès");

function onListsQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        var oListTitle = oList.get_title();
        //console.log("List Title: " + oListTitle);
        var listItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        var newItem = lstObject.addItem(listItemCreationInfo);
        newItem.set_item('Title', oListTitle);
        newItem.update();
    }
}  


function onListsQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log("Failed: "+ args.get_message());
}
},"sp.js");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see following issues in the code:
In the line

```
 var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
```

the variable 'lists' is undefined, it is not assigned/declared in your code.
Replace

```
var listObject=context.get_web().get_lists();
```

with

```
lists=context.get_web().get_lists();
```

where lists is a global variable
The line

```
 var lstObject = lists.getByTitle("Droits d'accès");
```

should be outside the while loop.

Also, you need to call context.ExecuteQueryAsync(successMethod,failureMethod) after adding
the items to the list, i.e after the update statement.

Refer here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185011(v=office.14)

Comment: Thanks for your response ! It works! I will put my code in my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to get all list titles from SharePoint site using JSOM:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var lists = web.get_lists();
    clientContext.load(lists);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onListsQuerySucceeded, onListsQueryFailed);

    function onListsQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
        var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
            var oListTitle = oList.get_title();
            console.log("List Title: " + oListTitle);
        }
    }  

    function onListsQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        console.log("Failed: "+ args.get_message());
    }
},"sp.js");
```

**Reference**:

1. [How to: Retrieve Lists Using JavaScript](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185009(v%3Doffice.14))
2. [How to get all the list names in a site from the client side?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42368/how-to-get-all-the-list-names-in-a-site-from-the-client-side)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ganesh ! Your solution works but I didn't wan't to have them in the console but to add each title in a list. It works thanks to the answer of Sourav. I will pu my code.

Comment: ok, I can provide the code to add list titles in another list if you want.

Comment: With the code that I have put in my question, adding the list titles in another list already works. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Great, keep using this platform for your queries and questions.